# HVM is required for this operation

Tags: xenserver

I have XenCenter 7.6 standard and I have a HP AMD Compaq pc with virtualization technology enabled (I checked in BIOS) but when I try to create a new VM and start it I get "HVM is required for this operation"... looks like XenServer's installed doesn't really see the virtualization technology which is enabled by BIOS.. any trick? Thanks to all! Cheers!

Comment: _XenServer's installed doesn't really see the virtualization technology which is enabled by BIOS.. any trick?_ No trick, but your PC must have the "correct" virtualization, of course. Seems like yours doesn't.

Comment: hello Lenniey....thanks for your answer... you mean maybe I should use an Intel processor PC than AMD processor pc to have "correct" virtualization, right?...

Comment: Not necessarily Intel, but either a compatible AMD one: http://hcl.xenserver.org/cpus/?cpusupport__version=14&vendor=1 or a compatible Intel one http://hcl.xenserver.org/cpus/?cpusupport__version=14&vendor=2

Comment: Thanks Lenniey , at this point I'm gonna create a PV guest with a Centos 6.10 so at least on this machine PV is supported.